# CSS styles question

Tags: css

Is there a way to add special characters `&diams;` through CSS styles if so can you show an example that works on most browsers?

Comment: What do you mean by "add"? Add where?

Comment: Add to the page where the styles are being USED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible, as such.

When using `:after { content: }`, you cannot specify HTML tags nor entities in the content string. You can, however, specify the symbols directly. (This is because the content string is not parsed as XML/HTML, but as plain text, and is inserted verbatim.)

In other words: `a:after { content: "&lt;" }` will yield the equivalent visual to `<a href="#">Some Link</a>&amp;lt;`.

`a:after { content: "♦" };` will work perfectly, tho'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :after and :before pseudoelements, however they are not supported by all browsers, have a look at

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_after.asp 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_before.asp

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit. As I don't think its as straightforward as `a:after {content: " &diams;";}`

Answer (score 0):

You should always avoid using CSS content because it's wrong to mix presentation with content of the page.

Additionally, CSS content is [not supported by some browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter_content.html), i.e. by IE6 and IE7.

If I wanted to do it, I'd use CSS to attach background image and add some HTML element around the word:

```
<style type="text/css">
abbr { padding-right:20px; 
background:url("http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/2005/blackdiamond.png") right no-repeat; }
</style>

<abbr>Something</abbr> very very Important goes here.
```

Result:

[image]

The only problem is - if I can modify the HTML to wrap my word with `<span>` or `<abbr>` or any other HTML element I could probably just wrtite &diams; in the code itself... your call.